# How to handle the Index, Create, Delete, Details and Edit view inside a TabStrip?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm starting to use the Kendo UI complete for ASP.NET MVC 4. 
I already created the database and the models that I need, but now I want to be able to handle (Index, Create, Delete, Details and Edit) the entities inside the content of each Tab. But I don't know how can I do this inside de tabstrip. (I started with the Internet Application template which has already a HomeController)

My code until now is:

**/Views/Home/Index**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                .Name("tabstrip")
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    items.Add().Text("Students").Selected(true).LoadContentFrom("Index","Student"); //Add item with text "Students"
                    items.Add().Text("Teachers"); 
                    items.Add().Text("Schools"); 
                })
)
```

**/Controllers/StudentController**

```
 public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private MiniSIGEdb db = new MiniSIGEdb();

        //
        // GET: /Student/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var students = db.Students.Include(s => s.Person).Include(s => s.School);
            return PartialView(students.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Student/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Person_id = new SelectList(db.People, "id", "FirstName");
            ViewBag.School_id = new SelectList(db.Schools, "id", "City");
            return PartialView();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

**/Views/Student/Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<MiniSIGEweb.Models.Student>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Course)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.School.City)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.School.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Until now I'm able to show de Index view (as partialview), but when I click in "Create New", the Create view is not rendered inside the tabstrip? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since your tabstrip is loaded with Ajax it means that each of the other views for edit, create ,delete should also be loaded with Ajax.

You can take a look at the [MVC Ajax links helpers](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2011/04/26/howto-ajax-actionlink-asp-net-mvc-3/). Create some result element inside of the tabstrip which should be updated with the content loaded with Ajax.